# finite difference time domain grid question

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

The finite difference time domain method is a finite difference method for solving maxwell equations numerically. There are several pieces to it, but this is the root of my question

$H_{i +1/2 , j+1/2}^{n +1/2} = H_{i +1/2 , j+1/2}^{n -1/2} + \space ....$

when $n=0$ we see that the stencil go out of the the time domain ($t \geq 0$, but the point would be $t-\frac{\Delta t}{2}$), which in english means that we need information before the initial condition was specified to move forward in time. Some help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: You should have derivative information at $t=0$ (as I recall Maxwell's equations are second order in time). Use that to provide the required information for the first time step.

Comment: I agree, for something like wave equation this would be true - since its a second order equation. Maxwell equation is only a first order equation in time though. Thoughts?

Comment: Oh, you're right, it is only first order in time. In that case your method, as a half-step type method, will need to do something different in the very first step from the rest of the method. There are techniques for this, but they depend on the context, the order of the method in the interior, etc.

Comment: Good point - that give me something to chew on. Thanks!